# Find anagrams JavaScript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, anagram

Lets Say I have a list like

Dog
dOg
God
doggy
dogg
Zebra
Wood

What I want to do is find all the words in the list regardless of case, or regardless of the actual word. I want to match the letters and take a count. So from above

Dog, dOg, God would all be a match and in this case would return "3" as the count, but doggy, dogg, zebra, wood.. would all be unique and all would return 1 as the count.. Though I know this is possible I don't know where to begin. The anagram concept throws me off a bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var words = new Array("Dog", "dOg", "God", "doggy", "dogg","Zebra", "Wood");
var unique = {};

// iterate over all the words
for (i=0; i < words.length; i++) {

    // get the word, all lowercase
    var word = words[i].toLowerCase();

    // sort the word's letters
    word = word.split('').sort().join('')

    // keep a count of unique combinations
    if(unique[word])
        unique[word] += 1;
    else
        unique[word] = 1;
}

// print the histogram
for (u in unique)
    document.write(u + ": " + unique[u] + "<br/>")
```

Comment: I hate it when the `new answer has appeared` bar comes up and it is the completed version of what you were writing. Good answer +1

Comment: me too. :) It's so frustrating.

Comment: looks like we were all thinking the same thing... haha

Answer (score 2):

here's what I came up with... [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hVUtp/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mywords = ['Dog', 'dOg', 'God', 'doggy', 'dogg', 'Zebra', 'Wood'];
    var finalArr = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < mywords.length; i++) {
        var temp = mywords[i].toLowerCase();
        var letters = temp.split('');
        var sorted = letters.sort();
        var final = sorted.join("");
        if(typeof finalArr[final] != 'undefined'){
            finalArr[final] ++;
        } else {
            finalArr[final] = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(finalArr);
    for(var i in finalArr) {
        alert(i + ': ' + finalArr[i]);
        document.write(i + ': ' + finalArr[i] + "<br/>");
    }
});
```